# Adding checkboxes into a ListView

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm currently trying to make my first app on android and I've gotten some problems. I'm trying to make a todo-list app so want some kind of input to be transformed into checkboxes. I've made it work with radio buttons using radioGroup. But when using Checkboxes with ListView it just doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText t;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkList = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void add(View view){

    t = findViewById(R.id.input);
    String s = t.getText().toString();

    CheckBox check = new CheckBox(this);
    checkList.add(check);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    checkList.get(i).setText(s);
    listView.addView(checkList.get(i));


    i++;
    t.setText("");

}}
```

The app crashes saying something about adapterView

Comment: how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: The app just crashes when testing it. It's the listView.addView that's causing the crash I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: No I don't think so. It's something with the code.

Comment: Where is adapter? It can not work without adapter.

Comment: that's exactly something with code. That question shows how to find a problem in code

Answer (score 0):

You're unfortunately doing something wrong here. You are trying to add your view to Listviews on

```
listView.addView(checkList.get(i));
```

This is not the correct way to use ListViews. You have to use an adapter. The adapter would need to provide data for the listview to load.

Please have a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial for how to use listviews.

Below is a summary of the steps to use a listView correctly.

- Create a new layout file (say `custom_cell.xml`) inside your layouts folder.
- Insert a checkbox inside your `custom_cell.xml` and place an Id which you can use later to identify the checkbox
- Create an adapter for your listview
- Override the `getView` method
- Inside the `getView` method, inflate a new cell using the `custom_cell.xml` or reuse an existing cell if provided
- Reference the Checkbox by using the Id you provided in the `custom_cell.xml` file

Comment: Is it a must to write all the code inside the

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

or is it ok to put it below as I did?

Comment: Hi @NZX: The problem is not where you have inserted the code.

You can not use a listview without using an adapter. Specifically saying, the line of code "listView.addView(checkList.get(i));" is wrong. You can not add a view like this to a listview. I'll define the correct way in my answer.